# Contact Form 7 - Make a selection unavailable after a number of bookings

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

Is it possible that a selection from a drop-down menu becomes unavailable after a certain number of bookings?

I am taking ticket bookings and they are in batches and I would like to have certain batches become unavailable after a certain amount of bookings.

Thanks for your help

Comment: how do you fill the drop-down menu ? edit your question to show the form code.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the [Smart Grid-layout Extension](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/) for CF7C plugin.  The smart grid plugin has a `[dynamic_dropdown]` tag which allows you to filter the options.

[image: dynamic dropdown tag creation screenshot]

Replace your dropdown menu with a dynamic dropdown and in the tag Custom Source select the Custom tab, you can then populate the dropdown dynamically using,

```
add_filter('cf7sg_dynamic_dropdown_custom_options', 'filter_options',10,3);
function filter_options($options, $field_name, $form_key){
  if($form_key != 'my-form') return $options; //check this is the correct form.
  if($field_name != 'bookings') return $options; //check this is the correct field.
  $options = array();
  //load all your booking options.
  foreach($bookings as $booking){
    //verify if the booking limit is crossed.
    if($booking->count < $limit){
      $options[$booking->id] = $booking->title; //$options are $value=>$name pairs.
    }
  }
  return $options;
}
```